# Continously shows Capacity used 90%

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I've two questions.

1. How to mount the directory for Ambari disk usage.
2. I started to run the tera gen program and it does not go beyond 10% map tasks, Ambari continously shows me the message that: **Capacity Used: [90.69%, 27.7 GB], Capacity Total: [30.5 GB], path=/usr/hdp** I restarted the cluster, restarted Ambari but no use.

What is the way around?

Answer (score 0):

Well,
After a few trial error I found the solution for the same.

1. You can change the location of log and local directories to bigger place
2. Remove the old log files from Ambari server.

Documented [here](https://hadooptips.wordpress.com/2015/10/16/fixing-ambari-agent-disk-usage-alert-critical/).